# Select between JSON data using JQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have the code below, which I am using to create a table and then populate it with data from JSON. My issue is that I have several data objects and would like to switch between them using select tag. Could you please help?

HTML

```
<select name="selector" onchange="onDataChange();">
    <option value="data1">RD1</option>
    <option value="data2">RD2</option>
    <option value="data3">RD3</option>
</select>
```

JSON Data

```
var data1 = [
    {"value":"RD01"}, 
    {"value":"RD02X"},
    {"value":"RD021ZX"}
];
var data2 = [
    {"value":"AX761"}, 
    {"value":"GT02X"},
    {"value":"GB051ZX"}
];
var data3 = [
    {"value":"BG761"}, 
    {"value":"OP02Z"},
    {"value":"FBL1ZX"}
];
```

JQuery

```
function onDataChange(){
    var select = $("select[name=selector]").val();
    //some logic
}
function buildTable(){
    var table = $(".code-table");
    for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        var row = "<tr><td>" + data[i].value + "</td></tr>";
        table.append(row);
    }
}
buildTable();
```

Comment: What is the problem here? Could you provide an example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: The data you posted isn't JSON, it's just JavaScript. The format is very similar but JSON doesn't have declarations like `var`

Comment: Thanks for comments, the issue is solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is just to add a parameter to `buildTable()`

```
function onDataChange(){
    var select = $("select[name=selector]").val();
    if (select == 'data1') buildTable(data1);
    else if (select == 'data2') buildTable(data2);
    else if (select == 'data3') buildTable(data3);
    //some logic
}

function buildTable(data){
    $(".code-table tr").remove(); //clear out table
    var table = $(".code-table");
    for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        var row = "<tr><td>" + data[i].value + "</td></tr>";
        table.append(row);
    }
}
buildTable(data1);
```